# AWS EC2 data out transfer to internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bandwidth

How Aws charges for data out transfer EC2 to internet? and also for first 100gb data out transfer is free for each month for that every month above 100gb data out transfer ec2 to internet. I mean, how they charge?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Answer (score 1):

From [EC2 On-Demand Instance Pricing – Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Data_Transfer) (in March 2022):

> **Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet**
> AWS customers receive 100GB of data transfer out to the internet free each month, aggregated across all
> AWS Services and Regions (except China and GovCloud). The 100 GB free tier for data transfer out to the internet is global and does not apply separately or individually to AWS Regions.

Pricing for data beyond 100GB is priced from 9c/GB, but it varies by regions. Please refer to that pricing page for current pricing.

Comment: 9c/GB, by the way, is much higher than any other server host that isn't "cloud" (which is more like 0c/GB to 1c/GB). So keep that in mind if it matters to you.

Comment: Yes, [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/) has cheaper packages with much more Internet Data Transfer volumes included.

Comment: IIRC you're not allowed to use all of it on purpose!